# How to output code text with numbers using Pod::Text::Termcap?

Tags: perl

I am trying to use [`Pod::Text::Termcap`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Text::Termcap) to output Pod as text to a terminal window. It works mostly very well, except for one case of displaying code text using the Pod `C<>` tag. Usually, `Pod::Text::Termcap` displays code text in double quotes, and this is fine. But, if I write code text containing only digits or a dollar sign followed by digits, the code text is no longer quoted. For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Pod::Text::Termcap;

my $pod_str = '=pod

This is a quoted name C<Peter>. The next text:  C<$1> , should also be quoted.

=cut';

my $parser = Pod::Text::Termcap->new();
my $str;
$parser->output_string( \$str );
$parser->parse_string_document( $pod_str );
print $str;
```

The output is:

> This is a quoted name "Peter". The next text: $1 , should also be
>   quoted.

Comment: This is not specific to Pod::Text::Termcap, but with POD formatting in general.

Comment: @Schwern Do you have any references?

Comment: `perldoc -oman` and `perldoc -otext` both have the same behavior (they were written by the same person).  `perldoc -ohtml` doesn't bother quoting, probably because the `<code>` tag makes it unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in [`Pod::Text->cmd_c`](https://metacpan.org/source/RRA/podlators-2.5.3/lib/Pod/Text.pm#L583) which was written by Russ Allbery back in 2001 and remains largely unchanged.  The function has comments explaining what was thought not to benefit from quoting.

```
# Apply a whole bunch of messy heuristics to not quote things that don't
# benefit from being quoted.  These originally come from Barrie Slaymaker and
# largely duplicate code in Pod::Man.
sub cmd_c {
    my ($self, $attrs, $text) = @_;

    # A regex that matches the portion of a variable reference that's the
    # array or hash index, separated out just because we want to use it in
    # several places in the following regex.
    my $index = '(?: \[.*\] | \{.*\} )?';

    # Check for things that we don't want to quote, and if we find any of
    # them, return the string with just a font change and no quoting.
    $text =~ m{
      ^\s*
      (?:
         ( [\'\`\"] ) .* \1                             # already quoted
       | \` .* \'                                       # `quoted'
       | \$+ [\#^]? \S $index                           # special ($^Foo, $")
       | [\$\@%&*]+ \#? [:\'\w]+ $index                 # plain var or func
       | [\$\@%&*]* [:\'\w]+ (?: -> )? \(\s*[^\s,]\s*\) # 0/1-arg func call
       | [+-]? ( \d[\d.]* | \.\d+ ) (?: [eE][+-]?\d+ )? # a number
       | 0x [a-fA-F\d]+                                 # a hex constant
      )
      \s*\z
     }xo && return $text;

    # If we didn't return, go ahead and quote the text.
    return $$self{opt_alt}
        ? "``$text''"
        : "$$self{LQUOTE}$text$$self{RQUOTE}";
}
```

The logic seems to be they didn't think it was necessary to quote things that already looked like code.  `$variables`, `function_calls()`, numbers, and code which was already quoted.  For a definitive answer you can email Russ.

If you want to know more, you may be able to glean some information from their git repository, but the commit entries shed no light on the decisions.

```
commit d374354c961250d1ee23342451713313fd934eda
Author: Russ Allbery <rra@stanford.edu>
Date:   Tue Jul 10 10:54:27 2001 +0000

        * lib/Pod/Text.pm (seq_c): Add heuristics to decide whether or not
        to quote the argument of C<>.

        * lib/Pod/Text.pm: Added a LICENSE section to the documentation.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference! What do they mean by `"not quote things that don't benefit from being quoted"`? If I write `C<$1>` I obviously want it to stand out in some way. Why remove the formatting indicated by the user?

Comment: @HåkonHægland I've updated the answer with my best guess.  I think they figured `$1` already stands out.